# Each child in a array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: react-native, key, prop

I have manually entered the key which is identical in db.json even though it is showing the same error

I have tried of adding unique keys manually in db.json even the error is reflecting in the same way. What is the error in this code so that I can rewrite it. I am unable to identify what is the error?

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  list: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#A9A9A9'
  },

});

class EventList extends Component {
  state = {
    notes: []
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const notes = require('./db.json').notes;
    this.setState({ notes });
  }

  render() {
    return [

      <FlatList
        key="flatlist"
        style={styles.list}
        data={this.state.notes}
        renderItem={({ item, seperators }) => (<EventCard notes={item} />)}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />,

      // <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#f3f3f3' }}>

        <ActionButton buttonColor="rgba(231,76,60,1)">
          <ActionButton.Item buttonColor='#9b59b6' title="New Task" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('form')}>
            <Icon name="md-create" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
          </ActionButton.Item>
          <ActionButton.Item buttonColor='#1abc9c' title="All Tasks" onPress={() => console.log("Hi")}>
            <Icon name="md-done-all" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
          </ActionButton.Item>
          <ActionButton.Item buttonColor='#00FF00' title="Camera" onPress={() => { }}>
            <Icon name="md-camera" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
          </ActionButton.Item>
        </ActionButton>
      // </View>


    ];
  }

}
var style = StyleSheet.create({
  actionButtonIcon: {
    fontSize: 20,
    height: 22,
    color:'#FF0000',
    opacity: 0,
  },
});


export default EventList;


          This is my  db.json file and I have written unique Id. I am getting a warning saying that each child should have a unique key. Here are my 2 files.



 {
        "events":[
            {
                "name":"chandu",
                "date":"15-06-2018 ",
                "content":"How are you..?",
                "id":"05dafc66-bd91-43a0-a752-4dc40f039144"
            },
            {
                "name":"bread",
                "date":"15-07-2018 ",
                "content":"I bought bread..?",
                "id":"05dafc66-bd91-43a0-a752-4dc40f039145"
            },
            {
                "name":"bharath",
                "date":"15-06-2018 ",
                "content":"I bought milk..?",
                "id":"05dafc66-bd91-43a0-a752-4dc40f039146"
            },
            {
                "name":"george",
                "date":"20-06-2018 ",
                "content":"I am eating",
                "id":"05dafc66-bd91-43a0-a752-4dc40f039147"
            },
            {
                "name":"michael",
                "date":"15-09-2018 ",
                "content":"I bought yogurt..?",
                "id":"05dafc66-bd91-43a0-a752-4dc40f039198"
            },
            {
                "name":"vick",
                "date":"15-04-2018 ",
                "content":"I bought milk..?",
                "id":"05dafc66-bd91-43a0-a752-4dc40f039157"
            },
            {
                "name":"shaun",
                "date":"09-06-2018 ",
                "content":"I bought milk..?",
                "id":"05dafc66-bd91-43a0-a752-4dc40f039120"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: Can you provide more details (e.g. what is the error, what are you expecting and db.json)? Please refer to
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: when I run this code I am getting warning as Each child in a array or iterator should have a unique “key” prop. How to make that warning disable.

Answer (score 0):

Your item within your db.json should have 'id' key with unique value for it to be used as key for your FlatList item, as what you write in your keyExtractor.

Comment: yes, id value is unique in db.json even though error is displayed

Comment: could you post your db.json content?

Comment: Yeah, I have edited the content and added db.json in the same file.

Comment: I notice your data contains id and is unique, but should your notes declaration be like this?

`const notes = require('./db.json').events;`

Comment: the problem isn't solved by changing const notes = require('./db.json').events; @user1677104.

Answer (score 0):

replace with this key Extractor in FlatList
**keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}**